# Rapid (1s) dual characteristic notification on Android won't disconnect from peripheral device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We've been working on a custom BLE peripheral gadget and writing an Android app to interface with it. We've discovered a failure mode that we can not seem to figure out.

The peripheral device has a number of characteristics, some of them marked as `PROPERTY_INDICATE`.

Normally the app works great. In particular, when we issue a `gatt.disconnect()` eventually followed by a `gatt.close()`, the device senses the disconnect and returns to advertising mode.

There is a mode the peripheral may enter though where it broadcasts changes to 2 characteristics with PROPERTY_INDICATE every second. When the peripheral is in that mode and we disconnect, the device never receives the disconnect. Somehow the android device (either a Samsung Tab2 or a Samsung S9) stays connected. We know it is connected, because until we power the handheld down, the device won't sense the disconnect. BUT, if you query BluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices() it shows 0.

We've done a number of iterations to try and triangulate on the cause:

- Reduce the characteristic count -> NO CHANGE
- Reduce the update rate to every 2 seconds -> SUCCESS
- Change one of the characteristics to use NOTIFY -> SUCCESS
- Interleave the changes so that we change both, but 0.5 seconds out of phase with each other, so they're not the exact same time -> NO CHANGE

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue? Or how to get closer to what's going on?

A quick fix for us would be the 3rd change. For this scenario NOTIFY vs INDICATE isn't that important. But it worries me to make that kind of change without understanding why.

We have an iOS variant of the app that doesn't have any of these issues. The iOS connection works fine (meaning it disconnects correctly) with the two indications happening every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After porting the app to use [SweetBlue](https://sweetblue.io) (a commercial offering that I was pretty impressed with actually), this behavior persisted. We will be modifying our peripheral to use PROPERTY_INDICATION sparingly, preferring PROPERTY_NOTIFY for any cases where the extra acknowledgment provided by INDICATE isn't critical.

At the end of the day my take away answer (until someone shows up with a better one) is:

## Android and PROPERTY_INDICATE don't mix/scale well. Developer Beware.